# int value passed with intents doesn't change second time despite onNewIntent()

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, onnewintent

I pass an integer value (guide) to the next class(activity) like this:
in different activities.. first:

```
                public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent002a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver002a.class);
                intent002a.putExtra("guide", 11001001);
                startActivity(intent002a);

            }
```

second:

```
                public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent003a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver002a.class);
                intent003a.putExtra("guide", 11002001);
                startActivity(intent003a);

            }
```

and so on..

Then I receive the intent:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over002a);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
    UnityAds.changeActivity(this);

    UnityAds.init( this, "*******", this);

    UnityAds.setDebugMode(true);
    UnityAds.setTestMode(true);


    TextView neinTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nein_textview002a);
    if (neinTextView != null) {
        neinTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Startbildschirm.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        });
    }


    TextView jatextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ja_textview002a);
    if (jatextview != null) {
        jatextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(GameOver002a.this)

                        .setMessage("Watch a short ad to continue at the last checkpoint?")
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                if (UnityAds.setZone("rewardedVideo") && UnityAds.canShow()) {
                                    UnityAds.show();
                                }}
                        }).create().show();



            }

        });
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

            .setMessage(R.string.zurück_zum_menü_frage)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Startbildschirm.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }).create().show();
}

@Override
public void onHide() {

}

@Override
public void onShow() {

}

@Override
public void onVideoStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onVideoCompleted(String s, boolean b) {
    levelAuswahl();
}

@Override
public void onFetchCompleted() {
}

@Override
public void onFetchFailed() {
    TextView jatextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ja_textview002a);
    if (jatextview != null) {
        jatextview.setText(R.string.videoladen_fail);
        jatextview.setClickable(false);
    }

}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    UnityAds.changeActivity(this);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

public void levelAuswahl() {
    int guide;
    guide = getIntent().getIntExtra("guide",0);
    if (guide == 11001001) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Story001a.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (guide == 11002001) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Story002b.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (guide == 11007001) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Story004a.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Startbildschirm.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

}

to choose the right activity.. EVERY PART OF THE STORY HAS HIS OWN ACTIVITY

following scenario:
I start the app and fail at the Story002a activity .. then I pass an integer value (guide) with an intent .. After watching an ad succesful the method levelAuswahl() is called (level chooser). it receives the intent and takes the right if clause and I start again at Story001.. THIS PART WORKS CORRECT
BUT.. if I fail at Story003a the value guide is passed with an intent exact as in Story002a..but this time in the the same activitie opens although I use onNewIntent()..

what do I need to change? Any ideas?

*Thanks in advance!*

here is the manisfest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".Startbildschirm"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Tutorial"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".Support"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".GameOver"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".Story001a"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".Story002a"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".Story002b"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".Story003a"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name=".Story003b"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

</application>
```

Comment: When the user "fails at some point in the story" - can you show us the code that you use to decide which activity should be open?

Comment: The two parts are runnning in the same Activity?

Comment: public void levelAuswahl() is the code to decide which activity should be open levelAuswahl = levelChooser in english

Comment: How you are calling levelAuswahl() method?

Calling from oncreate method ?

Comment: no ..after watching an video ad succesful ..this works correct

Comment: post your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
android:launchMode="singleTask" //or singleTop
```

is used

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

and everything works fine

use onNewIntent() like this to get your new intent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent);
// getIntent() should always return the most recent
setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` returns the `Intent` that the `Activity` was started with (ie: the one that caused `onCreate()` to be called. If you are returning to an existing instance of `GameOver`, and `onCreate()` is not being called, then you will get the new `Intent` delivered in `onNewIntent()`. The `Intent` passed to `onNewIntent()` should contain the correct extra value.

If this is not your case, please give more details about your situation.

Comment: Did i understand you right that the problem is that if I come to the  GameOver activty a second time the activity does not create a second time and therefore the var guide does not change? If yes could you please be more precise _where_ I have to use `onNewIntent` ?

Comment: Do you know if `GameOver.onCreate()` is being called the second time? Can you add logging to verify this? That would explain the behaviour you are seeing. If so, the question is: do you expect `onCreate()` not to be called the second time? Please post your manifest as I asked.

Comment: I used breakpoints and I stopped at onCreate() twice ..
How do I need to change the lines where i receive the intent? So what instead of: guide = getIntent().getIntExtra("guide", 0); ..?

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense. Please remove `android:launchMode="singleTask"` from the manifest and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I removed it as you said but now another mistake occurs.. edited in the question

Comment: Post the code from `Story003a` that starts `GameOver` with the extras.

Comment: I am now using onNewIntent but it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot follow you anymore :-( I don't know what your code is, what your manifest is, or what your problem is.

Comment: then i try to ask different.. What is the best way to have a var which you can use in every activity and you can change while the app is running? Everything I tried causes different problems and I cant find a good solution when I use google. .. And could you please start a chat? I dont want to spam the comments but I dont have enough reputation

Comment: Easiest way to have a shared variable would be to use a `public static` variable that can be accessed from anywhere. However, This can cause problems if your app goes to the background, gets killed and restarts. A safer alternative is to use `SharedPreferences`.